# CodeIgniter gives me error 404 but I can see response in Firebug

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have already read some questions very similar in SO, but none of the solutions worked for me.

The problem is, for example, with this code in the view:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'periodista/json',
async: false,
dataType: 'json',
success: function (json) {
$.each(json, function(k,v){valores.push(v); });

}
```

I get a 404 Not Found error, but Firebug shows me the Response (http://i.imgur.com/yG9cW.png)

I've tried to read the url response from a simple php script with file_get_contents function but it doesn't work

```
$url="http://localhost/xampp/populus/wordpress/app/periodista/json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

I get the same answer (404 error, and I can read the response in Firebug).

I've tried using the "index.php" URLs, the URLs without index.php with help of an htaccess, and using the complete URLs but nothing worked. And I'm not using wordpress.

I think the controller is not loaded when I try to access the view, but I don't know why.

Edit: My Controller function code (I'm using Ignited Datatables library):

```
    public function json()
{
    $datatables = new Datatables();
    $datatables->select('nro_boletin')->from('proyecto_de_ley');
    echo $datatables->generate();


    $data['title'] = "Periodista";
    $this->load->view('periodista/json', $data);

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in your controller?

Comment: @user1877722 pls add that code in your question (by editing it), not as a comment

Comment: You should not load view. Try `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));`

Comment: Sorry, there's the controller code.

Comment: Ok, but if I don't load view, how can I access the json() function?

Comment: You can still access the json() function as usual. But instead of rendering the view as response, you just send the json data as response. What you have in your view actually?

Comment: Nothing, but when I open the view, the json is echoed, and I actually can see it.

I don't know how to call the json() function without loading a view

Comment: Refer to @Sudhir's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I had to set header manually.

```
public function get_prev_input_data()
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $userdata = [
        "id" => 5,
        "username" => "captain hook",
    ];

    $prev = [
        "a1" => 123,
        "a2" => 46,
    ];
    $response = [
        "userdata" => $userdata,
        "previnput" => $prev
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

So you should add this line

```
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

in your **json()** function.

Answer (score 0):

try setting content type json and outputting it instead of loading view, like:

```
public function json() {
    $datatables = new Datatables();
    $datatables->select('nro_boletin')->from('proyecto_de_ley');
    echo $datatables->generate();


    $data['title'] = "Periodista";
    $this->output
               ->set_content_type('application/json')
               ->set_output(json_encode($data));
   //OR
   header('Content-Type: application/json',true);
   echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Since you are using ajax, your function is called

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'periodista/json', <-- your controllers function
    data: {"test" : "test" },
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) { //output from your json function
          $.each(json, function(k,v){valores.push(v); });
    }
```

Comment: How can I call this function without loading a view?

Comment: you need not load view, your controller function (json) is called from the ajax you are using

Comment: Ok, now this is weird. If I enter periodista/json I can see the json data, but only in chrome, in firefox it gives me a file not found.

Comment: can you try changing your ajax url to:: url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>periodista/json'

Comment: Thanks a lot but it still doesn't work. And I don't know if that's the issue because I cannot access the url with the file_get_contents method, and I don't know why when I don't load the view it doesn't work in firefox